# Use PowerShell to create a web page from an array

Tags: powershell

The goal of this code eventually will be go get all other web pages within a folder and create hyperlinks to file with the name of the files. This code mostly works but puts all elements of the array on both links. I need help to separate them links to 1 per file (per element of array until all created)

## Create a new web page

```
New-Item web.htm -Type file -force
```

## Put default opening html tag in file

```
Add-Content -Path web.htm -Value '<HTML>'
```

## Create an array to contain web hyperlinks to create

```
$pages = @('web1.htm', 'web2.htm')
```

## for each item add a link with the file name to open.

## *FAILS HERE CREATING BOTH PAGES FOR EACH MEMBER OF ARRAY*

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pages.Count; $i++)
{Add-Content -Path "Web.htm" -Value "<a href=$pages[i]> $pages[i] </><br>" }
```

## Close the html file tag

```
Add-Content -Path web.htm -Value '</HTML>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
New-Item web.htm -Type file -force
Add-Content -Path web.htm -Value '<HTML>'
$pages = @('web1.htm', 'web2.htm')
foreach($page in $pages)
    {
    Add-Content -Path web.htm -Value "<a href=$page> $page</a><br />" 
    }
Add-Content -Path web.htm -Value '</HTML>'
```

Comment: Your mistake is that there is no </a> tag.  I also changed the looping mechanism to a foreach as it is easier to follow and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Tony that did the trick but I do not have enough points to mark as the answer. Moderator please set Tony as answer.

Comment: @JoelT you can perform all actions on your own questions. I can see you've already given this the checkmark, but you should also be able to upvote it.